# When debugging in device with ART enabled, android app is slow

Tags: android, debugging, art-runtime

i dont know why but a week ago when i am debugging my app in android studio, the app in device is very slow, but if a generate the APK or use the play (Not debug) option works fine..

Anyone have idea why? I think i didnt any change in sdk or in the app to do it this..

Comment: Debugging always slows the app down. It's completely normal. You might not have noticed the delay before but it was always there.

Comment: No, its veeeery very slow, when i click in a button it take about 5-10 seconds in show a simple toast..

Comment: What is your version of AndroidStudio ? Did you look at IDE logs : C:\Users\<yourid>\.AndroidStudioPreview\system\log ?

Comment: Do you have ART enabled?

Comment: 0.5.6 i think its updated yesterday

Comment: Yes @StackOverflowException need i to do something special when i have ART and debug an app?

Comment: If you have ART enabled, the device will fall back to a slow (maybe non-JIT) interpreter when debugging. Combined with the need to check each instruction, it takes ages.

Comment: If you need faster debugging, you'll have to switch to Dalvik again.

Comment: Ok then..Thanks you. Put this as anwser and i will check as correctly

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When ART is enabled, the device cannot ensure the compiled code matches the bytecode instructions. It therefore cannot step through instructions and therefore lines.

This forces the device to fallback to a very slow interpreter, which possibly doesn't even JIT-compile.

For faster debugging, switch back to Dalvik.

Comment: This is pretty ridiculous! (I'm developing on my personal phone) So what happens when Android L hits devices with ART enabled by default?

Comment: You named a valid concern. I don't know? Let's hope they thought of something cool...

Comment: We can read  : Debug-time issue: Interactive debugging performance was slow, even in code without breakpoints. This has been addressed in the latest AOSP code.  (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html)

Comment: Thanks this was bothering me also. I had an app with background services using bluetooth for scanning. One of my test devices had ART enabled and was a hell to debug on. Showing black screens and non responding interfaces. Solved by switching it back to dalvik!

Comment: Why I didn't find this post before? The last two months have been painful to say the least. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, it seems we can't switch to Dalvik in Lollipop.  Debugging is really painful now.