# android - getting "this application maybe doing too much work" only when debigging

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, crash

I have an android app which runs great when I run it on eclipse on my **actual phone**.

But, when I want to debug it, it start to send messages like **skipped XX frames** and **this application maybe doing too much work on the main thread**, and the app runs extremely slow and crashes sometimes.

Only happens when debugging.. why is it? and how to fix it?

thanks!

Comment: Does it also happen when it is not attached to the pc and not in debug mode? The debugger is pretty slow so there is nothing to worry with that.

Comment: You mean when I run it from the phone without the pc? Works fine.  In debug  Its extremely slow..  Not something normal,  it worked fine just a while ago and I am not sure what made it so slow.  The weird thing  is it apperas only on debug mode

Comment: Yeah, the debug mode is pretty slow, without the pc attached it should work fine. There is nothing you can change about it unfortunately

Comment: There is actually, I found the issue. I updated my phone to have ART runtime (from Dalvik), and apparently it makes the debug really slow - read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300953/when-debugging-in-device-with-art-enabled-android-app-is-slow. so I switched back to Dalvik and it works fine :)